# Вопрос по поводу Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте. Пишу проект на Spring, в нем есть файл конфигурации *aplication.properties* в стандартной папке ресурсов проекта. Могу ли открыть его и менять после того как проект уже скомпилирован и установлен на глассфиш?  Хочется изменять настройки конфигурации не перекомпилируя каждый раз проект.  Как я могу сделать?

И еще вопрос. В проекте плохо работает Ajax запрос. Вот так выглядит веб страничка.

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="sendCommand('Start')" >запустить</a>

    <p> ответ от сервера : <span id="programmAnswer"> </span></p>

            <script>
                var programmAnswer = document.getElementById('programmAnswer');
                function sendCommand(url) {
                    statePrinter.innerHTML = "";
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
                    xhr.send();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                            programmAnswer.innerHTML = ' произошла ошибка при получении статуса';
                        } else {
                            programmAnswer.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        }
                    }
             }            
            </script>
```

вот контроллер :

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "Start" , method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json; charset=UTF-8"} )
    public String qwe()  {
        return thread.setStart() ? "программа запустилась." : "программа уже работает.";
    }
```

Сперва этот JS код был на обычном Web проекте с сервлетами и он замечательно работал. Но при взаимодействии со спрингом, он работает не корректно и даже не объяснимо

На одном компьютере под windows он не работает и возвращает 404.  А на другом компьютере на линуксе и с телефона все работает корректно, и возвращает 200.  Может кто-нибудь знает почему этот код ведет себя так загадочно ?

Answer (score 1):

Настройки специально выносятся в файл `aplication.properties`, а не забиваются напрямую в коде именно для того, что бы отказаться от компиляции всего проекта, если у вас сменился например URL базы.

Comment: Я и выносил настройки в специальный файл. Я написал об этом в вопросе.  Вопрос был, где найти в глассфише этот файл, после установки на него приложения.

Answer (score 0):

нужно было сделать ссылку посредствами Spring, вместо :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="sendCommand('Start')" >запустить</a>
```

сделать так:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="sendCommand('<c:url value="/Start"/>')" >запустить</a>
```